# Angular 2 - Select multiple objects from a component and display them in a parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am attempting to select multiple objects from a component and display only the selected objects in a parent component. I would like to make an api call from the child component, select specific objects from the child, then display them in the parent component.  Currently, I can only display all the objects from the api using the *ngFor loop, but I would like to select specific objects and list those objects in a parent component.

**item.component.html**

```html
    <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addItem()">Add New Item</button>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Description</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of Items" [class.active]="item === selectedItem" (click)="onSelect(item)">

                    <td>{{item.itemName}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.description}}</td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div *ngIf="selectedItem">
            <h2>
                {{selectedItem._id}} is my item
            </h2>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

**item.component.ts(child)**

```js
    export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

    Items: Item[];
    selectedItem: Item;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private itemService: ItemService){}        
        getItems(){

            this.itemService.getItems()
            .then(Items => this.Items = Items);
        }
        ngOnInit(){
            this.getItems();
        }
        onSelect(item: Item){
            this.selectedItem = item;
        }
```

**estimate-detail.component.ts**

```js
export class EstimateDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() estimate: Estimate;
    @Input() item: Item;  
    Items:Item[];        
    constructor(
        private estimateService: EstimateService,       
        private itemService:ItemService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getItems();      
    } 
   getItems(){
         this.itemService.getItems()
        .then(Items => this.Items = Items);
    }
```

**estimate-detail.component.html(parent)**

```html
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor=" let item of Items">
            <td>
            <a cart-button [item]="item" action="remove" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> X  </a>
            </td>
            <td><b>{{item.itemName}}</b><br>{{item.description}}</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: where are you using your ItemComponent?

Comment: the item component has its own route and displayed on its own page. The user can select the items button to be directed to a list of items.